# awk - problem with printf

Tags: awk

(edit: Problem solved, I used windows-generated files on a mac and the problem was the line endings. opening the file in studio code and setting  proper line endings solved this for me)

I have files generated by `ProduKey` that I want to process with **`awk`**.

ProduKey produces output like this:

```
==================================================
Product Name      : Microsoft Office Professional 2013
Product ID        : 00000-00000-00000-00000
Product Key       : 00000-00000-00000-00000-00000
Installation Folder : C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\
Service Pack      : 
Build Number      : 
Computer Name     : PC-000-0
Modified Time     : 06.12.2018 14:03:44
==================================================

==================================================
Product Name      : Windows 10 Pro
Product ID        : 00000-00000-00000-00000
Product Key       : 00000-00000-00000-00000-00000
Installation Folder : C:\Windows
Service Pack      : 
Build Number      : 17763
Computer Name     : PC-000-0
Modified Time     : 18.07.2019 09:50:37
==================================================
```

I want to generate csv files from that to store key, computer name and product name to a database later.

so a possible csv could look like this:

```
PC-000-0;Microsoft Office Professional 2013;00000-00000-00000-00000-00000
```

My approach so far:

```
    BEGIN {
    RS="\n\n";
    FS="\n";
}
{
    if ($1 ~ /Product Name/) {
        split($1,productArray,":")
        product = productArray[2]
    }

    if ($1 ~ /Product Key/) {
        split($1,keyArray,":")
        key = keyArray[2]
    }

    if ($1 ~ /Computer Name/ ) {
        split($1,computerArray,":")
        computer = computerArray[2]
        #print product 
        #print key
        #print computer
        printf("\n")
        printf("%s ; %s ; %s \n", computer, product, key)
    }
}
```

My problem is that I cannot concat the strings. Or maybe the strings are overriden by the moment i want to print them? I spend hours on this and would really appreciate your help/hints.

If there are more elegant ways to reach my goal feel free to tell me.

I am using `awk` on a Mac (awk version 20070501) but I have a Linux box as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with awk's record separator (`RS`) here. Setting it to `==================================================` or `={50}` which is the same thing but as a regex, lets you treat each set of values associated with a single product as a single "line". If you then set the output field separator (`OFS`) to `;` and the input field separator (`FS`, or the `-F` option) to `\n` (newline) or `:`, that lets you do little tricks like this (using GNU awk):

```
$ awk RS='={50}' \
      -v OFS=';' \
      -F'[\n:]' \
      'NR%2==0{print $16,$3,$7}' file 
 PC-000-0; Microsoft Office Professional 2013; 00000-00000-00000-00000-00000
 PC-000-0; Windows 10 Pro; 00000-00000-00000-00000-00000
```

Since each entry has a `=============================================` (50 `=`) above and one below, we only want to read every second "line". That's what the `NR%2==0` check does.

There are some extra spaces there, one at the start of each ine and another between the fields. If they're a problem, you can remove them with `sed`:

```
$ awk -v RS='={50}' \
      -v OFS=';' \
      -F '[\n:]' \
      'NR%2==0{print $16,$3,$7}' file | 
        sed -e 's/^ //' -e 's/; /;/g'
PC-000-0;Microsoft Office Professional 2013;00000-00000-00000-00000-00000
PC-000-0;Windows 10 Pro;00000-00000-00000-00000-00000
```

---

The use of a regular expression for the `RS` is a GNU extension, so will probably not work on your macOS. If not, try this instead:

```
$ awk -v RS='=' \
      -v OFS=';' \
      -F'[\n:]' \
     'NR%50==1 && $2{print $16,$3,$7}' file |
        sed -e 's/^ //' -e 's/; /;/g'
```

Comment: If I use your snippet it only prints out a lot of ;;
I will try on a Linux box later, maybe this does not work with awk that is preinstalled on a mac.

Comment: @tux yes, it will work on Linux, but will print the `;` on non-GNU `awk`. But try the updated one. That should work with _any_ awk implementation.

Comment: Wow, the updated version works like a charm! I can only stare at it but I don't really understand how it works - I will try to figure that out and create a script. I want to use it on dozens of files. Thank you @terdon

Comment: @tux it probably won't work, actually. based on your comment here, you have a file with windows line endings. So first remove those with `sed 's/\r//' file > file.fixed`. The trick I'm using is the `NR%50==1`. That's because there are 50 `=`, and each of them defines a "line". Therefore, I want the 51st and then the 151st etc. In other words, all line numbers which return 1 modulo 50.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
awk -F' : ' '/^Product Name/{pn=$2}
             /^Product Key/{pk=$2}
             /^Computer Name/{print $2,pn,pk}' OFS=\; file
```

The field separator `FS` is set to `:` in order to get the field value with `$2`.

The output field separator `OFS` is set to `;`.

The string is printed everytime the keyword `Computer Name` is found.

Comment: i tried to use your snippet in my script, my script looks now like this:

BEGIN {
 RS="\n\n";
 FS=" : ";
 OFS="\;";
}
{
 
 if ($1 ~ /^Product Name/) { pn=$2 }
 if ($1 ~ /^Product Key/)  { pk=$2 }
 if ($1 ~ /^Computer Name/) { print $2, pn, pk };
 
}

but output is still gibberish,

;00000-00000-00000-00000-00000 2013
;00000-00000-00000-00000-00000

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @tux Please use the script *as is*.

Comment: as far as I understand your snippet cannot be used as script but for usage from command line only. If I am misunderstanding your snippet please let me know what the script should look like.

Comment: @tux the script from your comment should also work. Is there something strange with your file? Could it have been generated on a Windows machine perhaps or a _very_ old mac? Try running `head -n1 file | sed 's/.*\(.\)/\1/' | od -c`, does that show you a single `\n` at the end or is there a `\r` there? I just tested and get the output you describe if the input file has Windows line endings.

Comment: yes, you are right, ProduKey is a Windows App, all the files were generated on Windows machines. My output is 
0000000   \r  \n                                                        
0000002

so it is a problem with line endings i suppose, i should have known it. Thank you for pointing out, i completely forgot.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to create an array that stores the tag name to value mappings (`f[]` below) and then just print whatever values you want at the end of every record, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS=";" }
{
    sub(/\r$/,"")
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/[[:space:]]*:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^:]+[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
    f[tag] = val
}
/^=/ && (cnt++)%2 {
    print f["Computer Name"], f["Product Name"], f["Product Key"]
    delete f
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
PC-000-0;Microsoft Office Professional 2013;00000-00000-00000-00000-00000
PC-000-0;Windows 10 Pro;00000-00000-00000-00000-00000
```

With this same approach it's easy to convert your whole input file to a CSV too if you like:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS=";" }
!/^=/ {
    sub(/\r$/,"")
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/[[:space:]]*:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^:]+[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
    if ( !seen[tag]++ ) {
        tags[++numTags] = tag
    }
    f[tag] = val
}
/^=/ && (cnt++)%2 {
    if ( !doneHdr++ ) {
        for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
            tag = tags[tagNr]
            printf "\"%s\"%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }

    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        printf "\"%s\"%s", f[tag], (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }

    delete f
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"Product Name";"Product ID";"Product Key";"Installation Folder";"Service Pack";"Build Number";"Computer Name";"Modified Time"
"Microsoft Office Professional 2013";"00000-00000-00000-00000";"00000-00000-00000-00000-00000";"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\";"";"";"PC-000-0";"06.12.2018 14:03:44"
"Windows 10 Pro";"00000-00000-00000-00000";"00000-00000-00000-00000-00000";"C:\Windows";"";"17763";"PC-000-0";"18.07.2019 09:50:37";""
```

Change `OFS=";"` to `OFS=","` and the output will be a file you can double-click on in Windows to have it displayed correctly in Excel.